# Flow: Check if String Collection Variable is Null

Tags: visual-workflow, collection-variable

In my flow I have created a String Collection Variable which I am using to store Email Addresses.  I am passing the Email Address List to a custom Apex component, [Send Better](https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/).
If the Email List is empty Send Better throws an error (understandably).
I have added a Decision to skip if the Email Address List is Null, but this is not working - even when the List String is empty the Decision still sees it as not Null
I also tried to use an Assignment to count the Collection, but this always outputted 1.
As it is a Collection I cannot use it in a Flow formula.
I guess I could create an Apex Class to handle this, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Any and all creative solutions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Define another collection resource of the same type and leave it empty then compare the two to see if the emails collection is empty.

Comment: What is the logic you're using in the assignment that you've mentioned? I've used assignments to complete null checks like this in flow before.

Comment: Please elaborate on how this collection is set. If I create a new Flow and all I include are a Text Collection variable and a Decision element that checks `email_Addresses Is Null False`, and I do not assign anything to the collection, when I debug the flow it works as expected. Are you calling an Apex Action earlier that returns a List and assigns it to your collection? If so it is likely assigning an empty List - which is not `null`. You might want to A) change your Apex to `return null` rather than an empty List, or B) do something like `email_Addresses Contains @` rather than `null` check.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback!  Further up in the flow I was removing a value from the List String. This resulted in the List String value being '[]' instead of null.
I adjusted the so I did not have to use the value and the decision now works.

Comment: Should I change the subject on this so others know it was an error in the config?